# How to get the first word after linebreak and change it if nessasry

Tags: line-breaking

I want to get the first word after automatic line break, then check it and change it when needed. This is needed in traditional Arabic Spelling for some words.

for example when `foo` comes after auto line break (at start of new line) I want to change it to `FOO`.

Comment: you would need to use luatex for this it isn't really possible in pdflatex or xelatex, but after the line breaking if you change the word, the linbreaking may no longer work, can you assume teh size of the new word is always such that it will always be possible to change the word and re-adjust the spacing just in one line to re-justify the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are prepared to mark up the special words you can use a `\discretionary` (the same mechanism TeX uses to add hyphens) one disadvantage is that you can not have stretchy spaces in a discretionary so the white space before the word is fixed at its natural length (in a box)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\foo{\unskip\discretionary{}{FOO}{\hbox{ foo}}}

\begin{document}

one two three \foo\ four one two three \foo\ four
one two three \foo\ four one two three \foo\ four
\foo\ one two three \foo\ four one two three \foo\ four
one two three \foo\ four one two three \foo\ four
one two three \foo\ four one two three \foo\ four
one two three \foo\ four \foo\ one two three \foo\ four
\foo\ one two three \foo\ four \foo\ one two three \foo\ four
one two three \foo\ four one two three \foo\ four
one two \foo\ \foo\ three \foo\ four one two three \foo\ four
one two three \foo\ four one two three \foo\ four
\end{document}
```

the three arguments to `\discretionary` are the partial text at the end of the first line if there is a break (empty) the partial text at the start of the second line if there is a break (FOO) and the text to use if no break (space foo)